# How to clear overlays in jQuery UI map?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dictionary, overlay

I've write this code to create overlay in a map with Jquery ui map.

```
    function drawTratta()

{

$.getJSON('json/getTratta.php?mode=set', function(data) {

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [];

  $.each(data.coord, function(i, item) 
    {

    flightPlanCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitudine,item.longitudine));  

    });


 $('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Polyline', 
{  'path': flightPlanCoordinates,
   'strokeColor': "#FF0000", 
   'strokeOpacity': 0.5, 
   'strokeWeight': 3, 
   'fillColor': "#FF0000", 
   'fillOpacity': 0.35 });


});

    }
```

Well, the function draw a line correctly but don't know how to clear the line from the map! If I invoke the function again another line is draw over without cancel the previous line.

In Jquery ui map you can clear marker by use this function:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('clearMarkers');
```

Is there a similar function to clear Polylines overlay?

Please, someone help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Polyline - How do I remove it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565260/google-maps-polyline-how-do-i-remove-it)

Answer (score 4):

Using the jquery-ui-map plugin would be:

```
$("#map_canvas").gmap('clear', 'overlays');
```

For a specific type:

```
$("#map_canvas").gmap('clear', 'overlays > Circle');
```

Note the caps on those options (Polygon, Polyline, Rectangle, Circle).