# Remove previous polyline Google Maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing a polyline onto a google map however I am having difficultly removing the last line drawn if the user makes a mistake.

The code I currently have to draw the line is below:

```
poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(evt) {

    if (path.getLength() === 0) {
    //Enters on first click

      path.push(evt.latLng);
      poly.setPath(path);
    } else {
    //Enters on second click
      service.route({
        origin: path.getAt(path.getLength() - 1),
        destination: evt.latLng,

        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length;
              i < len; i++) {
            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);

          }
        }
      });
    }


    var latitude_longitude = evt.latLng;
    var latitude = evt.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = evt.latLng.lng();



    ///Saves the first click location
if(count === 0){

        var latitude_start = evt.latLng.lat();
        var longitude_start = evt.latLng.lng();

        var firstlat = latitude_start;
        var firstlng = longitude_start;

    /////Trying to calculate distance
    var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(firstlat, firstlng);///1st click - never changes
    document.getElementById("origin1").value = origin1;
    document.getElementById("startpoint").value = origin1;

    ////Calculate distance
    var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); ///Most recent click
    document.getElementById("destination").value = destinationA; ////Stores Destination

    var origin1 = document.getElementsByName('origin1')[0].value ////Retrieves value from text box 


         count ++;
}else{

    var origin1 = document.getElementsByName('destination')[0].value ////Retrieves value from text box 

    ////Calculate distance
    var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); ///Most recent click
    document.getElementById("destination").value = destinationA; ////Stores Destination


}

                ////Calculate distance
                var servicetime = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                  servicetime.getDistanceMatrix(
                    {
                      origins: [origin1],
                      destinations: [destinationA],
                      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,

                    }, callback);

  });
```

At the moment I can clear all the lines using the code

```
path.clear();
```

However I am struggling to clear the last line drawn.

Comment: Where are clearing the path? Also, assuming you already created `path` and `service` somewhere.

Comment: Try to read the official doc here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove You may also try the method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565260/google-maps-polyline-how-do-i-remove-it

Answer (score 2):

Mir Shakeel Hussain's answer is actually correct. I was looking for an answer and he gave it. His formatting and explanation is awful though. Here's how I've done it (complete code):

```
 var map;
 var poly; //the line
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 52.092876, lng: 5.104480},
    zoom: 8
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#addLines').click(toggleLinesButton);
  $('#undoLine').click(undoPolyline);
});

var mayDrawLines = false;
function toggleLinesButton (el) {
  if (mayDrawLines) {
    mayDrawLines = false;
    $('#addLines').removeClass('active');
    removePoly();
  } else {
    mayDrawLines = true;
    $('#addLines').addClass('active');
    createPoly();
  }
}

var polyLineListener = null;
function createPoly () {
  if (!poly) {
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly.setMap(map);
  }


  // Add a listener for the click event
  polyLineListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);
}

function removePoly () {
  google.maps.event.removeListener(polyLineListener);
  //poly = null;
  polyLineListener = null;
}

var polyIndex = 0;
//Mirrors the path array to find index to delete and such
var mirrorCoordinates = [];
// Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
function addLatLng(event) {
  var path = poly.getPath();

  // Because path is an MVCArray, we can simply append a new coordinate
  // and it will automatically appear.
  path.push(event.latLng);
  mirrorCoordinates.push(event.latLng);

  polyIndex++;

  // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    map: map,
    visible: false
  });

}

function undoPolyline() {
  mirrorCoordinates.pop();
  polyIndex--;
  poly.getPath().setAt(polyIndex, mirrorCoordinates[mirrorCoordinates.length - 1]);
  poly.getPath().removeAt(polyIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the below may help 
you may need to use array to hold each click event object.
then you can use that array to remove the element and redraw the new ployline.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            newaddLatLng(event);
    });
function newaddLatLng(event) {
    path = newPol.getPath();
    path.push(event.latLng);
    newLat.push(event.latLng);
    indx++;
}
```

//remove code

```
  newLat.pop();
    indx--;
    newPol.getPath().setAt(indx, newLat[newLat.length - 1]);
    newPol.getPath().removeAt(indx)
```

Comment: The answer is correct. But the formatting and explanation is shit.